# Running a phonegap app on an ios device

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cordova

I am trying to run a phonegap app on my ios device and I am failing miserably. I realized that when i did 'phonegap run ios' my application was failing silently so I installed the ios-deploy package with the perm-unsafe=true flag but that didn't work. Following that I tried opening the xcode.proj file on xcode and simulating, it worked on my first try however when i try to rebuild and resimulate again I am getting a

The entitlements specified in your application’s Code Signing Entitlements file do not match those specified in your provisioning profile. (0xE8008016).

error. Has anyone encountered this? Oh, and my simulators work fine both from command line and from xcode, it is the real device simulation I am having issues with!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the '--device' flag? Something like: phonegap run ios --device

Answer (score 0):

Your id (like com.bokesoft.ceo) in config.xml does not match the provisioningProfile you provided.

- What is your id?
- What is your provisioningProfile ?
- Do you hava a file in ~/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning\ Profiles/
  ?